# how to replace date in postgres with a static number

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am writing a Postgres procedure and I want to replace only date part of date with some static no.

eg:-

```
varDate Date default '2018-05-21';
```

Say I want to make this date as '2018-05-08';

Can anyone tell how to achieve this.

Till now what i have tried is this

```
varDate := varDate - interval '1 day' * 21 + interval '1 day' * 8;
```

The above expression gives me proper results. But is there any shortcut to change only the date part of the date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to change the day of the month to 8.

One way to do this is to "truncate" the date to the start of the month, then add 8 days:

```
vardate := date_trunc('month', vardate)::date + 8;
```

`date_trunc` returns a `timestamp` that's why the cast `::date` is needed.

Another option is to "build" a date based on the existing date:

```
vardate := make_date(extract(year from vardate)::int, extract(month from vardate)::int, 8);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `date_trunc('month', vardate)::date + 7` if he wants the day value to be `8`?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a number of days to the date so you land on the 8th day:

```
select vardate::date + (8 - extract(day from vardate) * interval '1 day'
```